# Start activity using AlarmManager, without Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I hope that someone has an answer for me:

I wonder if it is possible (and common) to use the AlarmManager for directly starting an Activity. The documentation does not explain this explicitly. It only describes the usage of Broadcastreceivers.

If it is possible to start my Activity directy, where will I receive the Intent (onNewIntent)?

Many thanks
Jean-Pierre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible (and common) to use the AlarmManager for directly starting an Activity.

Yes.

> The documentation does not explain this explicitly. It only describes the usage of Broadcastreceivers.

Using a `BroadcastReceiver` is the most common scenario. It is required for `_WAKEUP` alarms, if you want the device to reliably wake up when the alarm goes off.

Starting an activity from `AlarmManager` should be used for "alarm clock"-type applications, and little else. You have no idea what the user might be doing with the phone when your activity comes to the foreground, and they may get very angry with you if they feel that your intrusion is unjustified.

> If it is possible to start my Activity directy, where will I receive the Intent (onNewIntent)?

By default, a new instance of the activity will be created. If you use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, it will bring forward an existing instance of the activity, and you will get the `Intent` in `onNewIntent()`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/tree/master/19-Alarm/LunchList) demonstrates using `AlarmManager` this way. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/tree/master/20-Notification/LunchList) demonstrates user configurable `Activity`-or-`Notification` when the alarm goes off. Both of these are relatively deep in a series of tutorials, and so the apps are a bit complex.

Comment: Even if i'm late in writing back. Thank you for the answer. It helped me a lot :)

Comment: So this means when an AlarmManager wakes up a BroadcastReceiver and I want to do my work in its onReceive() I dont need to hold a wake lock, right?

Comment: @jakk: Yes, but bear in mind that `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread for your process, so your work must be very quick.