# Should I use AlarmManager or CountDownTimer for my application?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, countdowntimer

So I'm new to android and working on an parking alert application which takes time input as variable to initiate a countdown timer that will trigger an alarm/notification/sound before the countdown timer reach 00:00(example : 02:00 remaining). 
The problem is after the countdown timer is initiate, the application will eventually goes background (closed) and wait for the alarm/alert to be triggered.

I have gone through AlarmManager documentation and known that it allows the countdown timer to continue running even the application is closed.

But for CountDownTimer , can the countdown timer keep running in background and triggered after the application is closed?

Which 1 I should be using in this case?AlarmManager or CountDownTimer ?
Thanks and appreciate for any helps!

EDIT : I need to use both for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the AlarmManager.

Why: The AlarmManager can start a background service to run your alarm code in. This works even if your app is killed. The CountDownTimer won't do this. It simply stops when someone exits your your app.

The AlarmManager can also wake your device up if it's in a deep sleep mode. This is very useful because most phones enter deep sleep when the screen turns off.

Comment: thanks for the advice.If I'm using AlarmManager, is it compulsory for me to use WakeLock to keep the CPU/screen running?

I'm worried for the battery consumption as the countdown timer may take times(hours) to trigger the alarm after the application is closed(running in background). 
If it is required,is partial wake lock is sufficient for my case?

Comment: You don't need a wakelock until the alarm goes of. Once the alarm goes of you could use one to play sound for example.

Comment: Do I need to use Service as well or AlarmManager is enough~
While the apps is running background, I wish to resume the application from background (before the alarm trigger) to view the remaining time(example: 00:30 sec remaining).

Comment: You don't necessary need a Service, but I suggest you don't start an Activity directly as this might interrupt the user. Info about starting an Activity from the AlarmManager can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641141/start-activity-using-alarmmanager-without-broadcastreceiver